# WebServiceHost Large Input\Output string

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

Server Code:

```
WebServiceHost w = new WebServiceHost(typeof(WebHost), new Uri("http://localhost/Host");
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647;
binding.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
binding.ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas { MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647 };
w.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(WebHost), binding, "http://localhost/Host");
w.Open();


[ServiceContract]
public class HEWebHost
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "Host")]
    public string Host(string largeRequest)
    {
    // ... Some code
    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost/Host") as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "POST";
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
writer.Write(largeRequestString);
writer.Flush();
writer.Close();
writer.Dispose();

HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string output = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Even though I set the MaxReceivedMessageSize of the binding object, I still get "400 Bad Request".
The same code exactly, only with a small string input works perferctly well, so...
How can I make this code work whith larger input strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is wrong in your code. You are using a `WebServiceHost` (WCF REST programming model) and in basicHttpbinding  (WCF SOAP Programming Model). You can't mix the two approaches.

Use a ServiceHost **or** a WebHttpBinding to correct the issue.

Also, please note that for WCF REST style bindings, you need to make sure the IIS can support larger transfers - by default it's is 4096 (4 MB)

Check your web.config - do you have an entry like this?

```
<system.web>
     ......
     <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="32678"/>  
     ......
</system.web>
```

> Even though I set the MaxReceivedMessageSize of the binding object, I
>   still get "400 Bad Request"

It's just a "bad request". Check WCF server log to get the exact error message.